# Usage and nuance of あまりに vs あまりにも

Tags: word-choice, usage, set-phrases

WWWJDIC lists both あまりに and あまりにも to mean "too much; excessively; too" but are they exactly the same in term of usage and nuance?

> あまりに 《余りに》 (adv) (uk) too much; excessively; too
> Ex: 料理にあまりに時間がかかりすぎる。 Cooking takes up too much time.
>
> あまりにも 《余りにも》 (adv) (uk) too much; excessive; too
> Ex: それは彼にとってはあまりにも易しすぎる仕事だ。 It is too easy a task for him.

Can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I read](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1458054474) that the も adds greater emphasis. With that in mind, I can see it in the following translations:

> 私たちは、あまりに自分のからだを医者任せにしてきたきらいがあるのではないでしょうか。
>   Don't you think that we have tended to entrust (the care of) our bodies too much to doctors?
>   あの人はあまりに**も**内気でどうにも好きになれない。
>   He is ***so*** introverted, I don't think I'll ever grow to like him.
>   彼の離婚を二人の価値観があまりに違っていたことによる。
>   Their divorce was caused by the fact that their value systems were very different.
>   彼女があまりに**も**自分勝手だったので、一言言わないではいられなかった。
>   Because she was acting ***so*** selfishly, I couldn't resist saying something to her.